# Using jQuery to simulate the click of a link - outside of an iframe, which links to another domain?

Tags: jquery, parent, target

In my head this should be straight forward, but after testing I've discovered that it's not as easy as I thought!

What I am trying to do is click a link outside of an iFrame, which will trigger a dynamic 'quick view' lightbox even within the parent site (which is on a different domain).

For example:

```
<a class="quickViewLink" href="#"> VIEW TO PURCHASE </a>

<iFrame src="http://www.google.com/">
  <a class="quickViewLink" href="#"> Clicking this will simulate the click of the link outside of this iframe </a>
</iFrame>
```

I have tried target="_parent" and also tried to use jQuery to target a specific link with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: I do not have access to the site outside of the iFrame!** (this is where I'm getting stuck)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="quickViewLink" href="#"> VIEW TO PURCHASE </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickLink() {
        $('.quickViewLink').trigger('click');
    }
</script>
<iFrame src="http://www.google.com/">
  <a href="javascript: window.parent.clickLink()" class="quickViewLink"> Clicking this will simulate the click of the link outside of this iframe </a>
</iFrame>
```

Use it with jQuery.

Comment: Awesome! But I don't have access to the parent site outside of the iFrame (extremely irritating) is there anyway I could do this from inside of the iFrame?

Comment: I think you can't... Maybe someone else has a solution but I think it is impossible...

Comment: I'm convinced this is what I need! I'll see if anyone else has any input, but I think you may be right. I might have some convincing to do!

Comment: @LouisXIV 
I tried like this 
**JS**

`$('#btnIframe').click(function(){
$('#filecontainer').attr('src','http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/08kv6jqx/1/');
});
$('#btnlogout').click(function(){
$('#btniframeTest').trigger('click');
});
`
It doesn't work.
 [fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/bqswfw4q/1/).

Comment: Hey tvshajeer, I think you should open a new question, because it looks a bit different. I think what you're aiming to do is impossible but maybe someone else will have a solution for your issue.